# Two 3 way switches with only one 3-wire cable

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I have two 3-way switches that I wanted to install.  I unfortunately only ran one /3 cable between the switches.

I have the source at one box, 2 lights at the other box, and one /3 wire between them.

Is there a way to use the hot legs and eliminate one of the 3-ways to have a 2-way & 3-Way at one box and just a 3-way at the other box?  Or any other suggestions?  I really don't want to rip the drywall down to run another 3-wire.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. It would help _immensely_ if you were to [edit] this to include a drawing of what you've done here. Based on my reading of your text, it sounds like you've wired this up exactly as it should be, so my guess is that the text isn't descriptive enough. _mumblemumble a picture is worth 1000 words mumblemumble..._ :)

Comment: if i understand correctly, this is your wiring configuration, right?  this configuration uses X-3 between switches.  if so, what exactly is the issue?  https://ibb.co/4ZRwzGJ

Comment: (also, formatting makes things much more readable. ;D)

Comment: Not exactly.  I have two 2-gang boxes at each end.  I have a ceiling fan at one box where the 2 three ways were intending on controlling the light and fan separately at each location.  So 2 three ways at each 2-gang box at each location and only one 3-wire between the 2-gang boxes.

Comment: So you are talking about 2 SETS of 3-ways so yes you will need another cable

Answer (score 3):

##### Smart Switches To The Rescue!

It is impossible to *legally* (i.e., code compliant) do this without additional wires. A traditional 3-way switch circuit relies on having 3 wires between each pair of 3-way switches (and any intermediate 4-way switches):

- Two travelers - at any given time, one is a part of the "switched hot" chain and the other is dead.

One of:

- Hot
- Switched Hot
- Neutral

There are no spare wires. No, you can't use ground as neutral and cheat. And *even if you **dangerously** did that*, you would only have 4 wires - still not enough to get 2 3-way switch circuits running.

**Smart switches** are the solution. A smart switch designed for "3-way" setups can work a bunch of different ways, including:

- **Use existing wiring**, but with one traveler as hot and one as a signal. This won't help you here - not enough wires for two 3-way circuits - but is often easiest to install when replacing existing fully functional 3-way circuits.
- **Wireless**. Note that I did *not* say "WiFi". There is a difference. There are many different ways of communicating wirelessly within a small area. WiFi is actually often *not* a good choice because it requires more power than some other types of wireless communications and because interference with other WiFi networks (if it doesn't require connection to your primary WiFi network) can be a problem and/or connecting it to your primary WiFi network can be tricky.

and there are a bunch of other variations. What I would recommend here is a smart switch configuration where:

- The switches that actually connect to the light and fan are the "main" switches. That has the advantage of *not* having to run any "switched hot" wires between the two groups of switches. Your 3-wire setup then becomes hot (black), neutral (white) and a spare red wire.
- The switches at the other location can be either battery powered (often easiest, but require periodic battery replacement) or powered by the power available in that box. That box (whether it directly powers any switches at that location or not) will send hot and neutral to the "main" box.

Please stick with a name-brand UL or ETL listed product line. There are a ton of ways to design and build these devices. UL or ETL review and testing makes sure that the safety issues are handled appropriately. Among the possible problems with cheap imitations are:

- WiFi or other wireless interference (both caused by the switches and from other things interfering with the switches)
- Melting, burning or other serious failures
- Poor quality dimming and/or fan speed control (they are different functions, even though conceptually similar, and require different designs), including damage to lights and/or fans

and many more.